# UWP is not available in Windows Store after Published

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have deployed my UWP in windows store. The app is available in windows store, however, it can be accessed only using the link provided by MS https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh5cdck. The app is not available when I search in windows store. I have used exact name and alternate names, but it's not showing in windows store.

Any suggestion, why it it not available in windows store?

[image: Windows Store Image]
Thanks!

Comment: Now. It is available in the store. Please check it.

Comment: Still looking to find it in Store, unfortunately not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you every one, 
I emailed this to Microsoft and then I received reply with following statements:

> We have reviewed your app and have moved it up in rank such that you
>   should see it in the Search results soon.

Within 10 hours after this email, I saw my app in the store.

Thanks to Windows Store Policy Team!

Answer (score 3):

If your app is public (not Beta or Private) it'll take time to be available through the search (Site & Devices) .. around 72 Hours or more in some cases!

**UPDATE 1:**

That's odd.. I suggest to update the submission and make it Private (2nd option) then after your submission is published.. send another submission and make it Public (1st option).. maybe that will update the servers status and the cache..

Comment: thank you, It's published since 2 weeks, but nothing appears in windows store.

Comment: Then, I believe that your app is private, you can edit this by editing the submission to public

Answer (score 1):

Same here. My app not showing in the search result. 
It's bug windows store.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-ru/ba1c37da-861d-4108-b905-f1b574a401c6/app-disappeared-from-store?forum=wpsubmit

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/66d1e7d5-9185-419b-ae79-8f457d060f41/my-app-cannot-be-found-in-the-store?forum=wpsubmit

petition:

https://www.change.org/p/microsoft-satya-nadella-bill-gates-windows-store-policy-team-windows-store-fix-windows-store-search-by-title-and-by-keyword-none-searchable-no-results?recruiter=358739216&utm_source=share_petition&utm_medium=copylink